# Why would error / warning / success messages stack up when using a Service?

Tags: 7, services, sessions, cookies, status-messages

I have a mobile app that uses Drupal as an API. As you navigate the site everything works as normal with appropriate messages on errors, warnings, and successful form submissions.

After doing that a while, when I first go to any Drupal page, Drupal finally prints all the 20+ messages that had occurred while using the Service. I haven't investigated how the messages are stored, but it's either memory consuming and/or heavy on each subsequent request.

**How do you prevent messages from being stored for the next page load when those messages are already received via AJAX in the returned JSON.**

Some of these messages are from Core modules and others are my own necessary calls to `form_set_error` so that hook_node_validate does not execute the insert.

Comment: They're stored in the session so you'll need to clear them from there in a context that makes sense to your app

Comment: thanks @Clive, are messages stored in a consistent top-level $_SESSION['property'] ?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure they're in `$_SESSION['messages']`

Comment: great @Clive! then i just unset the session variable during an early hook - to only track the current request's messages - but i presume not all are invoked as normal during a Service request. Do you recommend a particular hook for this?

Comment: meanwhile, this in an answer and it's yours... MUCHO MAHALO!